# multiple where clause in query failing

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to select the following query from my table:

```
SELECT ARTICLE_NO, USERNAME, ACCESSSTARTS, ARTICLE_NAME, 
date_format(str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), '%d %m %Y' ) AS shortDate 
FROM AUCTIONS WHERE SUBCAT = 'fake' and USERNAME = 'testuser' ORDER BY 
str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), article_no limit 0, 10
```

I get 0 results back.

However, both

```
SELECT ARTICLE_NO, USERNAME, ACCESSSTARTS, ARTICLE_NAME, 
date_format(str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), '%d %m %Y' ) AS shortDate 
FROM AUCTIONS WHERE SUBCAT = 'fake' ORDER BY 
str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), article_no limit 0, 10
```

and

```
SELECT ARTICLE_NO, USERNAME, ACCESSSTARTS, ARTICLE_NAME, 
date_format(str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), '%d %m %Y' ) AS shortDate 
FROM AUCTIONS WHERE USERNAME = 'testuser' ORDER BY 
str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), article_no limit 0, 10
```

return the expected result sets. Why are they not working together?

Comment: please break your code across multiple lines for easier comparison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHERE SUBCAT = 'fake' and USERNAME = 'testuser'

Should be:

WHERE SUBCAT = 'fake' **OR** USERNAME = 'testuser'

this will return both results which is what you're after right?

Edit:
Sorry, misread the fields. Add the "SUBCAT" column into your queries so you can see how many occurences there are with each one and make sure the combination will produce results before applying both where clauses.

Comment: the AND would be impossible to evaluate because it can't be both values but it could be one OR the other.

Comment: why? I want to select all records that have the category fake belonging to the user testuser. Surely using OR will result in all the records in the fake subcategory with any user?

Answer (score 2):

i think, that you have no result with a combination of "fake" AND "testuser"? (do you mean OR?)